# Are there other ways to introduce a new property/method to a variable in django template?

Tags: python, django

I am looking at one of sentry's templates and it is giving me an error `INVALID CONTEXT VARIABLE: MESSAGE.GET_STATUS_DISPLAY`. The template looks like this:

```
<span class="status status-{{ message.status }}">
    {{ message.get_status_display }}
</span>
```

The django docs says that when it encounters a dotted name after a variable like `message.get_status_display`, it will resolve it in this order:

1. Dictionary lookup
2. Attribute lookup
3. Method lookup
4. List-index lookup

I have scoured the source code and I have discovered that `message` is a model object and it doesn't contain anything resembling `get_status_display`. It, however, has a `message.status`. Can someone provide hints on how the dispatch to `get_status_display` is implemented ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`status` has `choices`, therefore `get_status_display()` is [created by the ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display).

Comment: Ah! Looks promising. Let me investigate further.

Comment: You rock. I am able to continue now. Thanks